# Search Not Appearing In Toolbar (Even with hardcoded toolbar height value)

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I want to implement a search feature in my application, I want to add the search bar on my toolbar. My toolbar shows up, but the search is not there (blank toolbar). How can I fix this?
I've searched around the site and some were solved by hardcoding the toolbar height, this doesn't work for me. What's the problem in my code?

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.m_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

And my `toolbar_search` looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#005caa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And my `search_menu.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/m_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

In my Activity, I just include the `toolbar` in my layout like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.MActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_search" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you upload your complete code

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty I had left out the rest of the XML for the Activity file. I just put up the rest of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're including a toolbar instead of directly implementing one. Instead of

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_search" />
```

use

```
<androidx.appcompat.Toolbar xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#005caa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

directly.
Then, return true in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, and before that do this:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        //do whatever you want on text submit
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        //do whatever you want on text change
        return true;
    }
});
```